# MySQL SELECT women not men

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my database called categories which holds the categories of a clothing store topics (New Arrival, Top Sellers, Men, Women, Kids etc)

I have one record that has: New Arrival, Men
I have a second record that has: New Arrival, Women

How could I query the database to select just women or just men?

I've tired this: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories RLIKE [[:<:]]Men[[:>:]]'`

This does work for men but it doesn't work for women.

Comment: What about OR condition WHERE category = Men OR category = women?

Comment: This is why we have [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). There should  be a separate table: `Categories`. Tied to the `Products` table via `FOREIGN KEY` in a `ProductCategories` junction table. Basically, **you are doing it wrong.** What you are doing is covered in [*SQL Antipatterns*](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book, **first** chapeter: Jaywalking.

Comment: @SpikeX I read the question...dont be rude.  The schema is poorly designed big difference.

Comment: @tereško haha. See my answer on that ^_^

Comment: @Neal, damn .. i hoped to say, that i was faster, but the timestamps are identical.

Comment: @tereško holy monkeys. wow. I have never seen two timestamps soo identical! How the....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you are **actually** storing the words "Men" or "Women", your database is set up **incorrectly**

You should be using a linked table let us say `categories` to link products to categories.

Then you can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM products p
JOIN categoriesToProducts ctp ON ctp.productId = p.productId
JOIN categories c ON c.categoryId = ctp.categoryId
WHERE c.categoryName = "Men";
```

Comment: Thanks, I will rethink my structure.

Comment: @m1a2x3x7 no problem, happy to help ^_^

Answer (score 1):

just use this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories LIKE 'Men%';
SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories LIKE 'Women%';
```

only use the right %

Comment: or create a category table, join prodcuts with categories and use somehting like 'WHERE category_id = x'

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `find_in_set function`, take a look to this example

```
mysql> select * from fruits;
+-------------------------------+
| fruit                         |
+-------------------------------+
| banana, apple, orange, grapes |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from fruits where find_in_set('banana',fruit);
+-------------------------------+
| fruit                         |
+-------------------------------+
| banana, apple, orange, grapes |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories where find_in_set('men',categories)'
```

be sure that the word after the `,` is exactly the same, without a extra space

Comment: @neal I'm agree with you, that's what I suppose that he wants, because we haven't even see the structure of the table or what he wants exactly

Answer (score -1):

You might want to just simplify your approach.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories = 'Men';
SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories = 'Women';
```

Since "Men" is apart of "WoMEN" this maybe the reason your sql is having issues?

However, since it was brought to my attention your DB might contain a longer string you might be able to do this as well.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories = 'New Arrival, Men';
SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories = 'New Arrival, Women';
```

Comment: The OP seems to have the **whole** string `New Arrival, Women` or `New Arrival, Men` in the database.... So this will not work....

Comment: He states he wants to select to Women or just Men... that is what i understood from his question.  Until we actually see his database structure we are just guessing.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don´t have problems selecting 'Women', you can solve it in case of Men by using a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE categories LIKE '% Men';
```

Just put a space before the letter 'M'.