# MySQL to fetch related users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables `Schools` and `Users`

Table School

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id |     name    |  city  |     major    | userID |
----------------------------------------------------|
| 1  |  school A   | chicago |    CS       |    1   |
----------------------------------------------------|
| 2  |  school B   | chicago |    CS       |    1   |
----------------------------------------------------|
| 3  |  school A   | chicago |    CS       |    2   |
----------------------------------------------------|
| 4  |  school C   | chicago |    Art      |    2   |
----------------------------------------------------|
| 5  |  school B   | chicago |    CS       |    3   |
----------------------------------------------------|
| 6  |  school D   | chicago |    Math     |    3   |
----------------------------------------------------|
| 7  |  school A   |New York |    CS       |    3   |
----------------------------------------------------|
| 8  |  school B   | chicago |    Art      |    3   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Table Users

```
--------------------
| id |     name    |
____________________
| 1  |    User A   |
____________________
| 2  |    User B   |
____________________
| 3  |    User C   |
____________________
| 4  |    User D   |
____________________
| 5  |    User E   |
____________________
```

The `userID` field in the `schools` table is a foreign key to the `id` field in the `users` table. I want to write a MySQL statement that takes a given `userID` and lists all classmates of that user.

So, for the example above, a class mate of  `User A` (ID#1) is a user that went to the same school as `User A`, is located in the same `city`, and has the same `major`. Thus, valid classmates for `User A` are only `User B` (ID#2) AND `User C` (ID#3).

Right now, I am using two MySQL statements to accomplish this goal. The first one is this

```
SELECT id FROM schools WHERE userID = '1'
```

which lists all schools for `User A`. Then I use PHP to loop through the results and for each row I run the following

```
    SELECT userID from schools WHERE 
name city LIKE '%$chicago%' 
AND name LIKE '%$school A%' 
AND major LIKE '%$CS%'
```

This works fine and returns the right list of userIDs. However, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this in one SQL statement and without having to use PHP.

Comment: Please redesign your tables. They are not normalized and could fall prey to many deadly things.... See Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11363740/561731 and related comments under the OP

Comment: Here is another comment that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363688/mysql-select-women-not-men/11363740#comment14970233_11363688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select distinct u.name
from Users u
join School s on s.userID = u.id
join (
            select distinct s.name, s.city
            from School s
            inner join Users u on u.id = s.userID
            where u.name = 'User A'
           ) aux on s.name = aux.name and s.city = aux.city
where u.name <> 'User A'
```

In the `aux` query you select the `name`'s and `city`'s of a `@user` and then select all `users` with those requirements and that aren't the `@user` itself.

You may replace 'User A' by a variable.

Answer (score -2):

Your SCHOOL table is not considered right. It violates the rules of relational database management systems.

One must make 3 more tables: one for school name, another for city name, and a third for major name. All of these must be different tables with ids.

Clearly name column and city column have a many-to-many relationship so one must make a lookup table for this.

The same applies for major column. It seems like a lot of tables but then your extraction of any value will be simple.

OK, I made some changes to your tables. I prefer this way to store the data:

```
table student
col.
id 
name
major
reg.no.   (to make each student unique)

table school
col.
id 
name

table city
col.
id 
name

table student_school (lookup table)
col.
student_id
school_id

table school_city
col.
school_id
city_id
```

Prefer these tables and you will find that every query can be made with ease. If you have any problem with understanding this, let me know.

Comment: I had to do a lot of work on this answer to make it legible, so in the future, could you follow this format when answering? In particular, we'd prefer if you not use textspeak abbreviations like "ur" for words like "your".